# Read sqlite db file in Databricks using PySpark, facing path not exists error in Community edition Databricks

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, databricks-community-edition

I tried reading with the following code :

```
df = spark.read.format('jdbc') \
          .options(driver='org.sqlite.JDBC', dbtable='employees',
                   url='jdbc:sqlite:/dbfs/FileStore/tables/chinook-1.db').load()
```

Its throwing the error like :

```
java.sql.SQLException: path to '/FileStore/tables/chinook-1.db': '/FileStore' does not exist
```

I have tried to give different methods of giving filepaths like :

```
/FileStore/tables/chinook-1.db 
dbfs:/FileStore/tables/chinook-1.db

dosenot work ,giving the same error.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The community edition doesn't support DBFS fuse, so you can't use `/dbfs` file path.  To access your sqlite database you need to copy file to the local disk using dbutils and then access it from there using the local file path:

```py
dbutils.fs.cp("dbfs:/FileStore/tables/chinook-1.db", "file:/tmp/chinook-1.db")

df = spark.read.format('jdbc') \
      .options(driver='org.sqlite.JDBC', dbtable='employees',
      url='jdbc:sqlite:/tmp/chinook-1.db').load()
```

Comment: So I have tried not only /dbfs , i have tried dbfs:/ , So these all come under DBFS Fuse? So i need to buy the premium version of databricks to run these kind of scenarios?

Comment: most probably SQLite doesn't understand cloud storage and works with files.